# How do I get my Flex box nav to resize to a smaller height for mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a simple flexbox layout made up of a parent element that contains two children elements.  The first child element (.child1) represents my menu, it's on the left, taking up about 0.125 of my viewport and spanning the entire height of the parent element.  The second child element (.child2) represents my content, it takes up the remainder of the width of the page.

I have it set up for when the viewport shrinks to a point were .child2 hits it's flex-basis of 400px it wraps below and the page layout becomes a psuedo "column" style layout. When .child2 wraps,  I want the height of .child1 to shrink to something like 50px and or a height more suitable for mobile nav. However, in my code, when the viewport gets down to mobile size, both child elements take up equal amounts of height.

how do I shrink .child1 's height when the elements are wrapping but have it full height when the elements are not wrapping?

*if it's possible to do this without media queries that would be ideal.

```css
.parentContainer {
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: LightCoral;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.child1 {
  background-color: DarkTurquoise;
  flex: 2 2 100px;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  flex: 20 1 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <div class="childContainer child1">
  </div>
  <div class="childContainer child2">
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Javascript solution would be to detect if the child element changes size, but this is a bit out dated, Spend some time learning about CSS media queries, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have to use a media query for when you hit the breakpoint as a property or two will need their value to change. Why are you against media queries?

Comment: @hungerstar I'm not against them, I was just curious if it could be done without them. It seemed like something that would be possible and I am just trying to minimize my code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple..

change the flex basis from px to %

Such as:

```
.child1 {
background-color: DarkTurquoise;
flex: 2 2 25%;
}

.child2 {
background-color: DodgerBlue;
flex: 20 1 75%;
}
```

Then add in this simple media query..

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
.parentContainer{  flex-direction: column}
}
```

This will swap things round but keep similar proportions..

If, of course you decide you want a bigger or smaller Nav in Mobile.

You can add the following to the media query..

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
.child1{  
flex-basis: 50%
}
.child2{  
flex-basis: 50%
}
 }
```